# Having trouble compiling in VS Code terminal, which is Windows Powershell

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, g++

When I right click Run code, and have run in terminal on in my user settings I get these errors.

> ```
> At line:1 char:63
> + ... "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\" && g++ Exe ...
> +                                                                ~~
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
> At line:1 char:99
> + ... \Learning to Program\" && g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercise36 && "c:\Use ...
> +                                                                ~~
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
> At line:1 char:102
> + ... ercise36 && "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\ ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
> At line:1 char:160
> + ...  "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\"Exercise36
> +                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
> Unexpected token 'Exercise36' in expression or statement.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
> ```

I have been compiling fine up until today, and I did some googling and started typing my own commands into the terminal instead of just running code.

I started replacing the `&&` with `-and` and get a different problem. This is what the command looks like now.

```
"c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\" -and g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercise36 -and "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\"Exercise36
```

This is the error I get.

> ```
> Set-Location : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'o' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -OutVariable -OutBuffer.
> At line:1 char:87
> + ... \Programming\Learning to Program\" -and g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercis ...
> +                                                                ~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
> ```

I am using the GNU open source compiler, this is the first issue I have had with compiling since I realized you have to save before you compile. I am running a simple string that changes all the characters to X from a string that is read from terminal from C++ Primer program. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I change "&&" to ";" I don't get errors anymore but I do get a different result to anything I expected, is this something I need to change json files for or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I believe it is caused by the new VS code version 1.35.
I tried downgrading to 1.34 and compiling and running c++ worked again.

The old version seems to run the code with a different command:

> "cd $dir ; if ($?) { g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt } ; if ($?) {   .\\$fileNameWithoutExt}"

in your case it would look like:

> cd "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\" ; if ($?) { g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercise36 } ; if ($?) { .\Exercise36}

For me using this comand compiling and running works in the new VS version aswell.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem

PS:

```
C:\typescript_practice> tsc testclass.ts && node testclass.js
```

> At line:1 char:18
> tsc testclass.ts && node testclass.js
> ~~
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

> PS C:\typescript_practice> tsc testclass.ts |  node testclass.js
> Sangamesh Vastrad

worked with below

**use** `|` instead of `&&` in latest for node

Comment: use pipe symbol

Comment: There is different behaviour between ``|`` and ``&&`` or ``;``. I think Semicolon ``;`` carries out commands sequentially, the equivalnt of ``&&`` .

Answer (score 5):

Okay, the problem is that VS Code default terminal is **Windows Powershell**
So you have to change your default terminal to **Command Prompt**

1. Click on the **Dropdown** which shows **Powershell** besides the **+** sign for new terminal
2. Click on **Select Default Terminal**
3. You will see options to select from, select **Command Prompt**

Then those commands will be executable

Answer (score 1):

Only a guess what you might need:

```
# change to the directory, where your source code resides
Set-Location "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\" 

# Invoke compiler via the call operator = &
& g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercise36 

# change to the directory, where your binary resides
Set-Location "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\Exercise36"
```

You can execute these three commands if you divide them with a `;`:

```
   Set-Location "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\"; & g++ Exercise36.cpp -o Exercise36; Set-Location "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Programming\Learning to Program\Exercise36"
```

If you want to check the outcome of a command you can use the `$?` [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps from [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-react-progressive-web-application-pwa-b5b897df2f0a), I came across this issue when tried to run the **following command** inside the terminal on VS code version 1.39.2

```
npm run build && npm run start-sw
```

**Error**:

> ```
> At line:1 char:15
> + npm run build && npm run start-sw
> +               ~~
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
> ```

**resolution** was to run the same command in the Node JS command window;

Adding this here since it was the top post for this error on stackOverflow and may help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

instead of && use | it works for any language

Answer (score 0):

Had faced same issue with VScode terminal with latest updates,
Tried the same with CMD, it worked well.
Hence, give a try running the command in other shell, or cmd instead of VSCode terminal.

Comment: Wildly changing environments without diagnosing why it is not working is not a solution.  It is a work-around.  The OP was looking for a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of 9/2021, for anyone getting the "&&" error, the previous way did not work for me.

1. Go to "View" -> select "Command Palette"
2. Enter "terminal:Select Default Profile"
3. Set to command prompt

Try this solution instead:

1. Go to Settings
2. In the search settings box, type "@feature:terminal"
3. Find "Terminal > Integrated > Automation Shell:Windows
4. Click "Edit in settings.json"
5. Set the

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
   ```

In this way, the default terminal to run "Run C++ Program:g++.exe" becomes cmd.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please try to make your post readable. I fixed it for you this time, but please for next time, refer to Stack Overflow's https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting guide for help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can directly download this extension named Terminal in VS code to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program you just have to see what terminal is running if windows powershell is running then you should select it as the default terminal from the dropdown menu next to the '+' button in the terminal window and same process for other terminals.