# javac Foo.java && java Foo in windows vscode terminal not work

Tags: java, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'd like to command `javac & java` at the same time but it's not work and it return below exception :

```
At line:1 char:17
+ javac Demo.java && java Demo
+                 ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

[image]

if i run separately it's work

```
PS D:\git\ITWeiHanDEV\Java> javac Demo.java

PS D:\git\ITWeiHanDEV\Java> java Demo
```

[image]

ps :

- my version is java8
- it's `windows 10 visual studio code terminal`

Comment: What shell and terminal are you using?

Comment: @John  windows 10 visual studio code terminal

Comment: very similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56488308/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell versions 6.x and earlier, including Windows PowerShell, do *not* support `&&` and `||`**, the [pipeline chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators) - they're **only available in PowerShell [Core] 7+**

In 6.x and earlier, you can emulate the behavior of `&&` as follows:

```
javac Demo.java; if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { java Demo }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to change vscode terminal type to `cmd` not `powershell integrated console` and run below script and it's work

```
cd "d:\git\ITWeiHanDEV\Java\" && javac Demo.java && java Demo
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `cmd.exe`, the Windows legacy shell, has always supported `&&` and `||`, whereas PowerShell started supporting these operators only from v7.0